# VBA code to scrape data not cycling back and forth through a webpage. Also struggling to scrape value

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Good Day, I am developing a tool to scrape 'One-Way fees' off various websites. For a particular website, I am at a stage where I can navigate to the correct page but I cannot figure out how to scrape the One-way fee into excel. I also have an issue where I cant seem to click the 'back' button. My code "works" in that if you iterate through the script by pressing F8 you get to where you need to be. It sometimes falls over at the 'carclick.item(x).click part' if you run it normally. Please note that the One-way fee does not always appear. Its most likely to appear when the pickup and dropoff locations are different. The tasks my code needs to execute is as follows:

1. create the html object, then open the website.
2. Click the 'return vehicle to a different location' button to allow the code to access different drop-off locations.
3. I have ignored drop-off/pick-up times and dates for now as they do not affect the one-way fee and the website default values are adequate. (Also, I couldn't get that to work either)
4. The code then inputs two locations: one for pickup and one for drop-off.
5. The code then clicks the 'find vehicle' button. The page loads for a while.
6. This page shows multiple vehicle options. Each car block may have a 'book' or 'request only' button that needs to be clicked (highlighted in blue), after which, a new page opens revealing the one-way fee. (1315.79 in value for the example values in my code)
7. The code would then need scape the value and paste it into excel along with the car name and car group (usually a letter of the alphabet).
8. I would then need to click the 'back' button to get back to the vehicle choices and repeat for all car groups.

   9. The tool needs to then repeat this whole process for all location combinations( the one-way fee may be different even for same location trips but in opposite direction). I haven't got this far as I've been struggling. I really need help with step 7 and 8.

   > ```
   > Private Sub test1()
   > Dim appIE As Object
   > Dim ws As Worksheet
   > Dim wb As Workbook
   > Dim a As String
   > Dim b As String
   > Dim c As String
   > Dim x As Integer
   > Dim d As String
   > Dim e As Object
   > Dim l As Object
   > Dim PickUp As Object
   > Dim iL As IHTMLElement 'this declares the html object
   > Dim f As IHTMLElementCollection ' this declares the collection of html objects
   > Dim post As Object
   > Dim Ret As Object
   > Dim entry As Object
   > Dim pd As Object
   > Dim backbutton As Object
   > Dim carclick  As Object
   >
   > Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Hertz")
   > Set ws = wb.Worksheets("One Way Fees")
   > Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
   >
   > With appIE
   >     .Navigate "https://www.Hertz.co.za"
   >     .Visible = True
   >
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   > Do While appIE.Busy
   >     DoEvents
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   >     Loop
   >
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   >
   > Set g = appIE.document.getElementById("return-location")
   >     g.Click
   >
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   > Do While appIE.Busy
   >     DoEvents
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   >     Loop
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   >
   > i = 2 'For i = 2 To 3
   > With ws
   > a = 1267
   > d = 1261
   > b = "15 - May - 19"
   > c = "25 - May - 19"
   > End With
   >
   >     For Each g In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("return-location")
   >         If g.className = "return-location" Then
   >             g.Click
   >     Exit For
   >         End If
   >         Next g
   >
   > Do While appIE.Busy And e Is Nothing
   >     DoEvents
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   >     Loop
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   > ' finds the pickup branch in html and clicks selection
   >
   > Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("pickup-depot")
   >     For Each O In e.Options
   >         If O.Value = a Then
   >             O.Selected = True
   >     Exit For
   >         End If
   >         Next
   >
   > Do While appIE.Busy And e Is Nothing
   >     DoEvents
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   >     Loop
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   >
   > 'sets the return branch and clicks the selection
   > Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("return-depot")
   >     For Each O In e.Options
   >         If O.Value = d Then
   >             O.Selected = True
   >     Exit For
   >         End If
   >         Next
   >
   > Do While appIE.Busy And f Is Nothing
   >     DoEvents
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
   >     Loop
   > Do While appIE.Busy And l Is Nothing
   >     DoEvents
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
   >     Loop
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
   >
   > 'Clicking find a vehicle
   >     For Each l In appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
   >         If l.className = "btn" Then
   >             l.Click
   >     Exit For
   >         End If
   >         Next
   >
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
   > ' On Error Resume Next
   > Do While appIE.Busy
   >     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
   >     DoEvents
   > Loop
   > 'While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
   >
   > Set carclick = appIE.document.querySelectorAll(".select-vehicle")
   >     For x = 1 To carclick.Length
   >         carclick.Item(x).Click
   >
   > 'While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   > ' On Error Resume Next
   > Do While appIE.Busy
   >     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   >     DoEvents
   > Loop
   >
   > 'This is where I tried to scrape the One-Way Fee value of 1315.79
   >
   > 'ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".sidebar__list- item:nth-of-type(13) span:nth-of-type(1)").innerText
   >
   > Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   > ' On Error Resume Next
   >
   > Do While appIE.Busy
   >     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   >     DoEvents
   > Loop
   >
   > Set backbutton = appIE.document.querySelectorAll(".back.btn")
   >     backbutton.Click
   > While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
   >     Exit For
   >     Next x
   > End With
   > End Sub
   > ```

Comment: when I click request only I end up on an options page detailing extras. I still can't find the one way fee. What details and actions do I take to get exactly to the value of  1315.79

Comment: If you scroll down, below the picture of the car on the right hand side, there's a box called Quote details, the value is down there.

Comment: What from and to locations and vehicle was selected to get your shown price?

Comment: Pickup -OR Tambo. Dropoff- King Shaka Airport.

Comment: Aha!!!! So one-way fee is not always listed which is why I wasn't finding it.

Comment: @QHarr, I apologise,I should of mentioned that, The one way fee will most likely appear when its a different station drop-off. But not always...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193313/discussion-between-hev-and-qharr).

Comment: I really reccomend you indent your code.  As it stands I'm  not even going to try and read it

Comment: Thank you @chrisneilsen, I have tried to indent the code.